# Struggling On A Lesson About Classes & Subclasses of CodeHS

Tags: java

I spent two days in class  trying to figure it out, but I just don't understand some of the errors.

I actually found a similar question in this site but I still don't get it.

The lesson's name is 4.12.4 Clothing Store.

> In this problem, you’ll design a few classes that represent different
>   pieces of clothing in a clothing store.
>
> You’ll write the classes for TShirt, Jeans, Sweatshirt and Clothing.
>
> The Clothing class should have two instance variables: one for the
>   size of the clothing (a String), and another for the clothing’s color
>   (also a string).
>
> Clothing should have two accessor (getter methods) as well:
>
> ```
> public String getSize()
> public String getColor()
> ```
>
> The Sweatshirt class should have a private instance variable (or
>   field) to store whether or not it has a hood, and a corresponding
>   getter method
>
> ```
> public boolean hasHood()
> ```
>
> The TShirt class should have a private field to store the fabric and a
>   corresponding getter for that called
>
> ```
> public String getFabric()
> ```
>
> All Jeans should have the color blue.
>
> The constructors should be of this format:
>
> ```
> public Clothing(String size, String color)
> public TShirt(String size, String color, String fabric)
> public Sweatshirt(String size, String color, boolean hasHood)
> public Jeans(String size)
> ```

And the following is my code:

```
public class Clothing
{
    public String size;
    public String color;

    public Clothing(String size, String color)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

}


public class TShirt extends Clothing
{
    private String fabric;

    public TShirt(String size, String color, String fabric)
    {
        super(size, color);
        this.fabric = fabric;
    }

    public String getFabric()
    {
        return fabric;
    }
}


public class Sweatshirt extends Clothing
{
    private boolean hasHood;

    public Sweatshirt(String size, String color, boolean hasHood)
    {
        super(size, color);
        this.hasHood = hasHood;
    }

    public boolean getHasHood()
    {
     return this.hasHood;
    }
}


public class Jeans extends Clothing
{
    public Jeans(String size)
    {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

My error:

> Errors: Jeans.java: constructor Clothing in class Clothing cannot be
>   applied to given types;
>
> Grader.java: You may have forgotten to declare hasHood() or it's out
>   of scope

Comment: What was your question?  I only understand that you don't "get it" but it's unclear what you're not getting, or what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jeans` passes just one argument to the super constructor. You don't have a one-argument constructor for `Clothing`. Either make `Clothing(String size)` or your `Jeans` class can pass a default value to the super. Like `super(size, "Blue")` or whatever is appropriate.

EDIT:

Change `getHasHood()` to `hasHood()`. Your class is enforcing naming conventions on you.

Comment: If you found it helpful, you can it as an accepted answer.

Comment: yeah sure, i'll do it right after the time limitation